# Downloading a Python audio file Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, librosa

I'm trying to upload an audio file to Jupyter Notebook(I work with librosa), I wrote the following code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as ipd
%matplotlib inline
import warnings
path = 'gruesome.mp3'
audio, sr = librosa.load(path, sr=44100)
```

I get the following error(tell me what the problem may be, I've already spent a lot of time, I can't solve the problem, how to solve the problem?):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oExJs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6sXT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GezBV.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is well covered in [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa#soundfile) readme.

In summary

1. libsndfile doesn't support MP3 due to patents.
2. audioread requires that you install ffmpeg or GStreamer.
   For conda installations, they recommend

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

You can also consider a different file format, e.g. FLAC or ogg

*Edit: I should also mention that this has nothing to do with Jupyter, nor with uploading or downloading anything.*

Comment: thanks for you answer, but i would like to ask you one more question: does librosa support WAV audio files?

Comment: It supports everything libsndfile does https://libsndfile.github.io/libsndfile/formats.html , or, if you install actually install ffmpeg, then pretty much everything there is.